# How do I make operations inside Select() method in LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

For example:

```
    db.Images.Select(image => new ImageViewModel{
Image64 = //I want to make calcuation on the image.Uri to convert it toBase64
});
```

I will download the image and convert it to Base64 then assign it to the `Image64` property of the `ImageViewModel`.
Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

I tried the following 
`Image64 = FromAzureToBase64(image.AzureUri),`
it throws this exception:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String FromAzureToBase64(System.String)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

this is the method (not tested):

```
private static string FromAzureToBase64(string azureUri)
{
    Uri blobUri = new Uri(azureUri);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(blobUri, StorageAccount.Credentials);
    using (MemoryStream stream = blob.OpenRead() as MemoryStream)
    {
        byte[] arr = stream.ToArray();
        var azureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
        return azureBase64;
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? I mean, it is as simple as `db.Images.Select(x => new { A = 1 * 5 });` for example. You can even call other methods like `A = GetSomeValue(x)`

Comment: I amended the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to enumerable list and then do your functions on it

```
var images = db.Images.Tolist();
var images_aft = images.select(/*Do here whatever you want*/);
```